# Create dummy variable based on if a number in a range appears in select columns

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I am trying to query multiple columns in my dataset to see if a number between 135 and 225 is present.

I've currently been doing it a very manual way, but this isn't sustainable since there are much more than only 2 columns I'm trying to query. How can I more efficiently code this so I can list 6+ column names without it being burdensome and long?

`sample_dates_test$day180_completion[(sample_dates_test$blood_day180_sincedx <=225 & sample_dates_test$blood_day180_sincedx >=135) |                                       (sample_dates_test$prevaxblood.dayneg7_sincedx <= 225 & sample_dates_test$prevaxblood.dayneg7_sincedx >=135]) <- "Complete"`

````
structure(list(record_id = 2:4, first_dose = structure(c(NA, 
18718, 18660), class = "Date"), second_dose = structure(c(NA, 
18745, 18688), class = "Date"), day0 = structure(c(18449, 18451, 
18462), class = "Date"), blood_it_plus2 = structure(c(18459, 
18464, NA), class = "Date"), blood_day180 = structure(c(18647, 
NA, NA), class = "Date"), blood_day90 = structure(c(NA, 18551, 
NA), class = "Date"), blood_it_plus7 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18470
), class = "Date"), blood_day30 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), class = "Date"), blood_day365 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), postvaxblood.day90 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), blood_day7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), blood_day0 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), postvaxblood.day30 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), postvaxblood.day7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), prevaxblood.dayneg7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), blood_it_plus2_sincedx = c(10, 
13, NA), blood_it_plus7_sincedx = c(NA, NA, 8), blood_day0_sincedx = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), blood_day7_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), blood_day30_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), blood_day90_sincedx = c(NA, 100, NA), blood_day180_sincedx = c(198, 
NA, NA), blood_day365_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), prevaxblood.dayneg7_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), postvaxblood.day7_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), postvaxblood.day30_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), postvaxblood.day90_sincedx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), first_dose_sincedx = c(NA, 267, 198), second_dose_sincedx = c(NA, 
294, 226), today = c(378, 376, 365)), reshapeWide = list(v.names = "enrollment_obtdatetime", 
    timevar = "redcap_event_name", idvar = "record_id", times = c("enrollment_arm_1", 
    "it__2_days_arm_1", "day_180__30_days_arm_1", "day_90__14_days_arm_1", 
    "it__7_days_arm_1", "day_30__7_days_arm_1", "day_365__60_days_arm_1", 
    "post_vaccine_day_9_arm_1", "day_7__2_days_arm_1", "day_0_3_days_arm_1", 
    "post_vaccine_day_3_arm_1", "post_vaccine_day_7_arm_1", "vaccine_day_7_to_1_arm_1"
    ), varying = structure(c("enrollment_obtdatetime.enrollment_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.it__2_days_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_180__30_days_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_90__14_days_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.it__7_days_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_30__7_days_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_365__60_days_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.post_vaccine_day_9_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_7__2_days_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.day_0_3_days_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.post_vaccine_day_3_arm_1", 
    "enrollment_obtdatetime.post_vaccine_day_7_arm_1", "enrollment_obtdatetime.vaccine_day_7_to_1_arm_1"
    ), .Dim = c(1L, 13L))), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: your code is not reproducible.  Please give an sample example and desired output in respect of that sample example

Comment: see my edited answer for the edited scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is named `sample`.  Do this

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

sample <- sample %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(any(between(c_across(17:28), 135, 225)), 'complete', 'incomplte')) %>% ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 x 32
#>   record_id first_dose second_dose day0       blood_it_plus2 blood_day180
#>       <int> <date>     <date>      <date>     <date>         <date>      
#> 1         2 NA         NA          2020-07-06 2020-07-16     2021-01-20  
#> 2         3 2021-04-01 2021-04-28  2020-07-08 2020-07-21     NA          
#> 3         4 2021-02-02 2021-03-02  2020-07-19 NA             NA          
#> # ... with 26 more variables: blood_day90 <date>, blood_it_plus7 <date>,
#> #   blood_day30 <date>, blood_day365 <date>, postvaxblood.day90 <date>,
#> #   blood_day7 <date>, blood_day0 <date>, postvaxblood.day30 <date>,
#> #   postvaxblood.day7 <date>, prevaxblood.dayneg7 <date>,
#> #   blood_it_plus2_sincedx <dbl>, blood_it_plus7_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   blood_day0_sincedx <dbl>, blood_day7_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   blood_day30_sincedx <dbl>, blood_day90_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   blood_day180_sincedx <dbl>, blood_day365_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   prevaxblood.dayneg7_sincedx <dbl>, postvaxblood.day7_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   postvaxblood.day30_sincedx <dbl>, postvaxblood.day90_sincedx <dbl>,
#> #   first_dose_sincedx <dbl>, second_dose_sincedx <dbl>, today <dbl>,
#> #   dummy <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I tried to do this and am now getting an error 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

```sample_dates_test$day_180_completion <- sample_dates_test %>%
  mutate(across(17:28), ifelse(between(.,135, 225), "Complete","Incomplete"))```

Comment: Thank you!! I never would've caught that. The ultimate goal was that I would add a new column to sample_date_test called day_180_completion, but it looks like this code isn't achieving it. I'm assuming I need to move day_180_completion = ___ down to the mutate line... but where?

Comment: I'd like to create just one new column. 

Added output above!

Comment: how would I write this to just create a single new column rather than one for each column? I want it to show as "Complete" if a value between 135 and 225 appears in any of the listed columns.

Comment: Sorry, just one new column in whole data.

Comment: @user16368087, the previous code was for one new column for each of 17:28 columns, the new edited code will create one new column only checking your condition in all 17:28 columns but returning output based on `any`